# MongoDB logrotate with occasional file size changed while zipping error

Tags: mongodb, logrotate

I use this script for rotating MongoDB v3.6.3 logs:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log {
        weekly
        rotate 52
        compress
        missingok
        notifempty
        sharedscripts
        create 644 mongodb mongodb
        postrotate
                /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /mnt/mongodb/data/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        endscript
        dateext
        dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
}
```

However, some times this error happens:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: Compressing program wrote following message to stderr when compressing log /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.2018-04-09:
gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping
```

What happens and how to avoid such error?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server (x.y.z) are you using?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 1):

Add delaycompress after the compress line.  It will zip it on the next rotation so you use a little more disk for longer, but it will release the file handle so you can avoid this error.

Comment: have tried it but does not work as expected. Here is the sample result: mongod.log.2018-08-26.gz (5212896 bytes), mongod.log.2018-09-03 (86384849 bytes), mongod.log (0 bytes). The newly created log has a size zero which shouldn't be the case.